use let command to draw single arrow shape with rotation angle
I found one good example code here, and try to reformat it with let command and define one newcommand for easy use.
Below is my draft version but can not pass compile:
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, calc}
\newcommand{\dbarr}[4] {
  \path (#1) -- (#2) 
    let 
        \p1=($(#1) - $(#2)),
        \n{height}={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
        \n{angle}={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
    node[midway, single arrow, draw=black, 
        minimum width=15mm, minimum height=\n{height}, 
        inner sep=0mm, single arrow head extend=1mm, double arrow head extend=1mm,
        fill=cyan!20,double arrow,rotate=\n{angle}] (#3) {#4};    
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \dbarr{A}{B}{C}{from A to B};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Error:
Runaway argument?
$(B)), \n {height}={veclen(\x 1,\y 1)}, \n {angle}={atan2(\y 1,\x 1)}\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \tikz@cc@parse@factor.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> a.tex
         
? x
No pages of output

This error is hard for me to understand where is the error.
appreciate if anyone can help me!

The code compiles if \p1=($(#1) - $(#2)) is replaced by \p1=($(#1) - (#2)$) (note the position of the $).
